# How to specify 'greedy identifiers with a space' in ANTLR?

Tags: whitespace, antlr, grammar, identifier, ambiguity

Suppose we have the input that looks like the sequence of simple English statements, each on a separate line, like these:

```
Alice checks
Bob bets 100
Charlie raises 100
Alice folds
```

Let's try parsing it with this grammar:

```
actions: action* EOF;
action: player=name (check | call | raise | fold) NEWLINE;
check: 'checks';
call: 'calls' amount;
raise: 'raises' amount;
fold: 'folds';

name: /* The subject of this question */;
amount: '$'? INT;

INT: ('0'..'9')+;
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n';
```

The number of different verbs is fixed, but what's interesting is that name that we are trying to match could have spaces in it - and verbs could potentially be parts of it, too! So the following input is valid:

```
Guy who always bets 100 checks
Guy who always checks bets 100
Guy who always calls folds
Guy who always folds raises 100
Guy who always checks and then raises bets by others calls $100
```

So the question is: *how do we define `name` so it is greedy just enough to eat spaces and words that we are usually treating as verbs, but is not super-greedy so that the verbs could still be matched by `action` rule?*

My first attempt at solving this task was looking like this:

```
name: WORD (S WORD)*;
WORD: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')+; // Yes, 1234 is a WORD, too...
S: ' '; // We have to keep spaces in names
```

Unfortunately, this will not match 'Guy who always bets', since `bets` is not a `WORD`, but a different token, defined by a literal in `bets` rule. I wanted to get around that by creating a rule like `keyword[String word]`, and making other rules match, say, `keyword["bets"]` instead of a literal, but that's where I got stuck. (I guess I could just list all my verbs as valid alternates to be a part of a `name`, but it just feels wrong.)

Here is what more: all the `name`s are declared before they are used, so I can read them before I start parsing `action`s. And they can't be longer than MAX_NAME_LENGTH chars long. Can it be of any help here?

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, anyway. ANTLR gurus, can I hear from you?

Answer (score 2):

The easy way out would be to enable global backtracking on your entire grammar. This is normally not recommendable, but I guess your grammar will stay relatively small, in which case it won't matter much on the run-time of your parser. If you do find it becomes slow, you could un-comment the memoize option which will make your parser faster, at the cost of some memory consumption.

A demo:

### in.txt

```
Guy who always bets 100 checks
Guy who always checks bets 100
Guy who always calls folds
Guy who always folds raises 100
Guy who always checks and then raises bets by others calls $100
```

### Poker.g

```java
grammar Poker;

options {
  backtrack=true;
  // memoize=true;
}

actions
  :  action* EOF
  ;

action
  :  name SPACES (bets | calls | raises | CHECKS | FOLDS) SPACES? (NEWLINE | EOF)
     {
       System.out.println($name.text);
     }
  ;

bets    : BETS SPACES amount;
calls   : CALLS SPACES amount;
raises  : RAISES SPACES amount;
name    : anyWord (SPACES anyWord)*;
amount  : '$'? INT;
anyWord : BETS | FOLDS | CHECKS | CALLS | RAISES | INT | WORD; 

BETS    : 'bets';
FOLDS   : 'folds';
CHECKS  : 'checks';
CALLS   : 'calls';
RAISES  : 'raises';
WORD    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
INT     : '0'..'9'+;
SPACES  : ' '+;
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n';
```

### Main.java

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PokerLexer lexer = new PokerLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("in.txt"));
    PokerParser parser = new PokerParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.actions();
  }
}
```

Running the Main class produces:

```
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/Poker$ java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool Poker.g 
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/Poker$ javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/Poker$ java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main
Guy who always bets 100
Guy who always checks
Guy who always calls
Guy who always folds
Guy who always checks and then raises bets by others
```

### EDIT

You could do it the other way around: negate the tokens that you *don't* want `anyWord` to match:

```java
// other parser rules
anyWord : ~(SPACES | NEWLINE | DOLLAR); 

BETS    : 'bets';
FOLDS   : 'folds';
CHECKS  : 'checks';
CALLS   : 'calls';
RAISES  : 'raises';
WORD    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
INT     : '0'..'9'+;
DOLLAR  : '$';
SPACES  : ' '+;
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n';
```

`anyWord` now matches any **token** except `SPACES`, `NEWLINE` and `DOLLAR`'s. Note the difference between `~` inside lexer rules (negates characters) and parser rules (negates tokens!).

Comment: It certainly looks like it requires backtracking because of the inherent ambiguity (well, thanks a lot, natural languages!). But what I was looking for is some recipe for making all 'keywords' fall into a single token category, because the actual grammar is much bigger and more verbose than what I posted. I really don't want to add a new alternative to ANY_WORD each time a new literal is introduced - there is about 40+ of them already, and it is far from complete.

Comment: @Stepan Stolyarov, there's no way around it: words either get tokenized as keywords, or as a `WORD`. You will have to account for it in a parser rule. You could do it slightly different though (see my EDIT).

Comment: Hmm, I think I like this idea. It's harder to come up with a new punctuation than with a new keyword. Thanks, Bart, I'll definitely try this one!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: split on whitespace, reverse the input word-by-word, then parse from the right instead of from the left. (This requires rewriting your grammar, of course.)

Comment: Uhmmm... No, sorry. I still care about my colleagues' sanity. And I'm afraid they care about mine, too.

Comment: @Stepan: I can understand :) My point is that the language you're defining really isn't ambiguous; I think it's even right-regular and a finite-state/RE solution would suffice.

Comment: It's not ambiguous, at least not for human beings, and not in the part that I demonstrated. I was just looking for advice on how to feed it to a LL(*) parser. Other solutions - I tried to set a pack of REs on it - are hard to maintain, slow, or whatever.

Comment: A compiled RE shouldn't be very slow on this task, but I understand if you want to use ANTLR. Very few tools are up to this kind of thing out-of-the-box.